# Flipping an unfair coin n times

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I’m flipping an unfair coin $n$ times.

$\mathbb{P}[X=head]=p$ where $p \neq \frac{1}{2}$.

What is the probability “head” appears an even number of times?

Thank you in advance for your time an effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We flip $2k$ heads ($0\leq 2k\leq n$) with probability:
$$\binom{n}{2k}\,p^{2k}(1-p)^{n-2k} $$
hence the probability of an even number of heads is given by:
$$\begin{eqnarray*} \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}\binom{n}{2k}\,p^{2k}(1-p)^{n-2k}&=&\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}p^{k}(1-p)^{n-k}\frac{1+(-1)^k}{2}\\&=&\frac{1}{2}(p+(1-p))^n+\frac{1}{2}(-p+(1-p))^n\\&=&\color{red}{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}(1-2p)^n}.\end{eqnarray*}$$